# How do I source_once in bash?

Tags: bash

What's a good way of sourcing in just once in bash.

Does bash store the paths of the files that have been sourced in or  do I need to make all `source`/`.` invocations go through a wrapper that will store those paths?

Is there a standardly available mechanism that will find what a source argument resolves to? `which` doesn't seem to work unless the file is executable.

Comment: We need more detail. In what context are you sourcing files that sourcing one multiple times is a concern?

Answer (score 8):

In each of your files that you might source, add a statement.  Suppose that the file `/etc/interface` is one of the files that you want to only source once, then format that file as follows:

```
if [ ! "$ETC_INTERFACE" ]
then
    # statements that you
    # want to source...
fi
export ETC_INTERFACE=Yes
```

This assures that the statements in `/etc/interface` are only executed once.  If a script tries to source it again, it will see that `ETC_INTERFACE` has been set and skip the body of the file.

#### Alternate Approach

Suppose that one does not want to modify the files that are to be sourced but it is OK to modify the scripts which source them.  In that case, source them as follows:

```
[ ! "$ETC_INTERFACE" ] && source /etc/interface && export ETC_INTERFACE=Yes
```

Comment: yikes. put that logic in the sourced file.

Comment: I'm doing this in my dotfiles because of the complicated rules for when those are included, but I was looking for something a little more flexible to better organize non-dotfile bash libraries of mine.

Comment: @PSkocik I do this in my dot files too.  I have, for example, several instances of it in my `~/.bashrc`.  What part of this do you see as not "flexible" enough?

Comment: You have to put boilerplate in every file you intend to involve in this, and you have to think up guard variables (actually you don't, you could use BASH_SOURCE[0] to make the boilerplate static) but still. I posted the flexible-enough-for-me solution I came up with. Still, you have my upvote (I mean, I am already using this :D)) .

Comment: You could reverse the logic for saving one level of intendation.

    if [ "$ETC_INTERFACE" ]; then return; fi

Answer (score 1):

Below is how I solved it:

```
#Store source-in paths in a global hash
declare -A SOURCES

#Resolve paths manually
path_resolve(){
  #Absolute paths resolve to themselves
  [[ "$1" =~ ^/ ]] && { echo "$1"; return 0; }

  #Otherwise resolve against $PWD and then $PATH items
  local search_path=$PWD:$PATH
  local IFS=:
  for p in $search_path; do
    [[ -r "$p/$1" ]] && { echo "$p/$1"; return 0; }
  done
  return 1
}

#Helper function
warn(){ echo >&2 "$@"; }

#AKA source_once AKA include_once
require(){
  local path=$(path_resolve "$1")
  [[ -z "${SOURCES["$path"]}" ]] && {
    SOURCES["$path"]=true
    . "$path"
    return 0
  }
  #Warn if a second `source` is attempted from the main scope of an interactive session
  [[ -z "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]] && {
    warn "$path already sourced in"
    warn "Use \`. '$1'\` to reload it"
  }
  return 1
}

#AKA source_relative_once AKA include_relative_once
#require relative to current file or $PWD if there's no current file
require_relative() {
 local dir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
 [[ -z "$dir" ]] && dir="$PWD"
 require "$dir/$1"
}

#source relative to current file or $PWD if there's no current file
source_relative() {
 local dir="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
 [[ -z "$dir" ]] && dir="$PWD"
 source "$dir/$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, I know.

If you know the name of a variable or function included in the file (which you should, if you're planning on using something from it - otherwise, why bother including it?), you can also use the declare builtin.  Suppose you have a source file "includefile" that you wish to include, that defines a variable "variable" and you only want to load it once.  As a short one-liner, you can use:

```
declare -p variable || . includefile
```

If "variable" is defined, the declare statement returns true (0) and also spits out the value with a little more info.  If it's not, it'll return false (1) and also spit out a message saying so (so you may want to redirect to /dev/null).  The || (or) operator uses lazy evaluation (which is what we want), so with the above, if declare returns true, the or will return true, so it doesn't evaluate the next statement.  If the declare returns false, then the || operator needs to keep evaluating, so it tries the next statement - which then sources "includefile".